# Select DataFrame columns with names that follow a given pattern in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pattern-matching, selection

I am working with a `DataFrame` that contains a large set of columns. I would like to be able to select a subset of columns that follow a given pattern.

Example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a_1': [1,2,3],'b': [2,3,4],'c_1': [3,4,5]})

   a_1  b  c_1
0    1  2    3
1    2  3    4
2    3  4    5
```

I would like to be able to select only the columns that are ending with `_1` (this can be expressed as `'.*_1'` using the regular expression syntax) resulting in:

```
   a_1  c_1
0    1    3
1    2    4
2    3    5
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a special method for this - [DataFrame.filter()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html):

```
In [178]: df.filter(regex=r'_1$')
Out[178]:
   a_1  c_1
0    1    3
1    2    4
2    3    5
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with mask by [`endswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.endswith.html) or [`contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with regex:

```
df1 = df.loc[:, df.columns.str.endswith('_1')]
```

```
df1 = df.loc[:, df.columns.str.contains('_1$')]

df1 = df.loc[:, df.columns.str.contains('.*_1')]
```

---

```
print (df1)
   a_1  c_1
0    1    3
1    2    4
2    3    5
```

Comment: Is it possible to use regular expression instead?

Comment: @KrzysztofSłowiński - yes, need second solution with `contains`

Comment: Thanks, Is this a duplicate question since it gets down voted?

Comment: @KrzysztofSłowiński - There is main reason why your question is downvoted there is no your code, what you try.

Comment: OK, good to know.

Answer (score 0):

You could use list comprehension to select columns that end with `_1`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a_1': [1,2,3], 'b': [2,3,4], 'c_1': [3,4,5]})
filter_col = [col for col in df if col.endswith('_1')]

df[filter_col]

   a_1  c_1
0    1    3
1    2    4
2    3    5
```

Comment: Sure, I was thinking about a more general approach though, so it is not only applicable to this one particular case, that's why the solution using regular expression is selected.

Comment: No problem. You can accept the answer that meets your needs :)